# Replacing Delimiter In CSV Files with Python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, str-replace

I have a folder with several CSV files. These files all contain the box drawing double vertical and horizontal as the delimiter. I am trying to import all these files into python, change that delimiter to a pipe, and then save the new files into another location. The code I currently have runs without any errors but doesn't actually do anything. Any suggestions?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

directory = 'Y:/Data'
dirlist = os.listdir(directory)
file_dict = {}
x = 0

for filename in dirlist:
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        file_dict[x] = pd.read_csv(filename)
        column = file_dict[x].columns[0]
        file_dict[x] = file_dict[x][column].str.replace('╬', '|')
        file_dict[x].to_csv("python/file{}.csv".format(x))
        x += 1
```

Here is a picture of sample data:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample of the said CSV files?

Comment: Hey, I think you should use index 1 to obtain the first column and not index 0. If I am not wrong, index 0 represent a column with line numbers. So, the code would be: column = file_dict[x].columns[1]

Answer (score 1):

```
with i as open(filename):
    with o as open(filename+'.new', 'w+):
        for line in i.readlines():
            o.write(line.replace('╬', '|'))
```

or, skip the python, and use `sed` from your terminal:

`$ sed -i 's/╬/|/g' *.csv`

Assuming the original delimiter doesn't appear in any escaped strings, this should be slightly faster than using the regular `csv` module. Panada seems to do some filesystem voodoo when reading CSVs, so I wouldn't be too surprised if it is just as fast. `sed` will almost certainly beat them both by far.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly replacing occurrences with the new character (which may replace escaped occurrences of the character as well), we can just use built-in functionality in the csv library to read the file for us, and then write it again

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv', newline='') as infile, open('outfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='╬')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Adapted from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Fair. I took what i consider to be the fairly safe assumption that the creator of the source data file used that delimited because they lack the concept of "escaping."